# my program of searching file does not search folder inside folder

Tags: python, recursion

I have made a file search program which search for the file. it is working fine with searching in current working directory and also inside one folder, however it does not work folder inside folder, I am not getting why? Can anyone please help?

My Code:

```
import os

files = []
def file_search(file, path=""):
    if path == "":
        path = os.getcwd()
    for item in os.listdir(path):
        if os.path.isdir(item):
            path = os.path.realpath(item)
            file_search(file, path)
        elif item == file:
            files.append(item)
    return files


print(file_search("cool.txt"))
```

Comment: Look at what happens inside the `if os.path.isdir(item):`, you never do anything with the result of `file_search(file, path)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it will be simpler if you used `glob` library.

**Example:**

```
import glob

files = glob.glob('**/cool.txt', recursive=True)
```